# Logic - Interpret a different input

Tags: java

Basically, instead of reading one value from the user and converting it to yen. I want to enter a string of values and convert each of those values to yen.

For example, the code below will only convert one value entered until zero is entered. Then the program will not run.

How would I make it take a string of floating-point values such as:

```
34.4 4.9 34.0 9.98 0
```

And convert that into yen while still terminating when it reaches the zero?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P4Point27 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String convert = "Enter Dollars to Convert to Yen (Enter '0' to Quit): ";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the Price of $1.00 Dollar in Japanese Yen: ");
    double dollarToYen = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.print(convert);
    double dollars = in.nextDouble();
    while (dollars != 0) {
    double price = dollars * dollarToYen;
        System.out.println("$" + dollars + " is " + price + " yen.");
        System.out.print(convert);
        dollars = in.nextDouble();
    }
    in.close();
}
}
```

Input:

```
9 8 7 0
```

Output:

```
Enter the Price of $1.00 Dollar in Japanese Yen: 9 8 7 0
Enter Dollars to Convert to Yen (Enter '0' to Quit): $8.0 is 72.0 yen.
Enter Dollars to Convert to Yen (Enter '0' to Quit): $7.0 is 63.0 yen.
Enter Dollars to Convert to Yen (Enter '0' to Quit):
```

As you can see it ignores the 9, and it also keeps reprinting the status message.
I believe using a do-while loop will fix it missing the 9 or a for-loop but I am unsure.

---

Fixed the code! Working Code!

```
package assignment4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class P4Point27 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the Price of $1.00 Dollar in Japanese Yen: ");
    double dollarToYen = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter a String of Numbers Seperated by a Space and Terminated by a '0' to End: ");
    double dollars = in.nextDouble();
    while (dollars != 0) {
        while (dollars != 0) {
            double price = dollars * dollarToYen;
            System.out.println("$" + dollars + " is " + price + " yen.");
            dollars = in.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter a String of Numbers again or '0' to quit: ");
        dollars = in.nextDouble();
    }
    in.close();
}
}
```

Comment: It already does that. If you think it doesn't, maybe I'm not understanding your question. Can you be more specific about the behavior you're expecting?

Comment: It does work but my logic with the printing is wrong and I am unsure on how to fix it.

I'll edit so that you can see the output.

Comment: Updated post with working code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't "miss" the 9. That's the value it uses as the "$1.00 in yen" value. Then it correctly converts the 8 (8 * 9 = 72) and the 7 (7 * 9 = 63) and then exits when it sees the 0. Part of your problem may be the repeated printing of the "Enter Dollars to Convert...". Since you print that message each time your loop is executed, it shouldn't be surprising that it appears once for each execution of the loop.

**Update:** `System.out.print(convert);` is the code that's printing your status message. You should arrange your code so that statement is executed however many times you want the message to appear. If you only want to see it once, then that statement shouldn't appear inside any loop since loop bodies are (typically) executed multiple times

Comment: I understand that it is probably really obvious that the printing error is easy to fix but I cannot see it.

I do see the mistake with the 9. It is not ignoring it. That was my fault for forgetting it does the conversion value first.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution. It uses the  `split()` function, on a delimeter here the comma. Then parses each of the comma-seperated values to a double, and applies the arithmetic. Otherwise the code is rather self-explanatory.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P4Point27 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String convert = "Enter Dollars to Convert to Yen (Enter '0' to Quit): ";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the Price of $1.00 Dollar in Japanese Yen: ");
        double dollarToYen = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print(convert);

        String dollarString = in.next();
        String[] dollarArray = dollarString.split(",");
        double[] dollarDoubles = new double[dollarArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < dollarArray.length; i++) {
            dollarDoubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(dollarArray[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dollarDoubles.length; i++) {
            double price = dollarDoubles[i] * dollarToYen;
            System.out.println("$" + dollarDoubles[i] + " is " + price
                    + " yen.");
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

This is a sample run of the program:

```
Enter the Price of $1.00 Dollar in Japanese Yen: 5
Enter Dollars to Convert to Yen (Enter '0' to Quit): 3,4,5
$3.0 is 15.0 yen.
$4.0 is 20.0 yen. 
$5.0 is 25.0 yen.
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment as well. I probably should get user input using comma's but we have yet to learn arrays so we are not allowed to use them in class.